# How to connect between two aws instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab

I have an aws instance which hold Gitlab app and I have another for holding database, how can I achieve the connection between with two instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second instance is only there to store a database (and it's something like postgres or mysql) I'd recommend using RDS for it instead.  It sets up the database in a way where you can whitelist the security group of the EC2 instance (your gitlab app) and provides dns and automatic backups/replication (if you enable multi-AZ).

This guide is a good place to start:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.PostgreSQL.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your security group allows your instances to reach one another by modifying the inbound connection to reach the host on the required ports.

Start your database on the one instance

Your app should be able to connect to the database onces its up

For psql for example you would do something like

```
psql -h <DATABASE AWS INSTANCE IP> -p <port> -U <username> -W <password> <database>
```